# Laravel 5.2 New Password Must differ from Old One

Tags: php, laravel-5

Currently I am working on one project's authentication module. I want to create functionality of password reset with the constraint that new password and old password must be different. But the problem is, the password is encrypted with `bcrypt` in database. So I can't use `Different` validation rule on that field. I can accomplish it by creating additional function, but I want to do it with single validation with basic password validation like `AlphaNum` `Between` etc. Is it possible to do it without creating custom validation rule ? My code is following:

```
$data = Request::all();
$rules=array("username"=>"Required|Exists:users","password"=>"Required|AlphaNum|Between:6,64|Confirmed");
```

Thank you

Comment: Make a custom validation that checks if the new password is same as old password for the give email/username

Answer (score -1, accepted):

laravel has reset password  library.
It is very easy to use.
see it
[resetting-passwords](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#resetting-passwords)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I couldn't get much about it as I am new to laravel. Do you have any link which can explain it thoroughly ?